# after using the angular route SignalR is not working

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

The problem is if i first load the "#/chat" my signal R chat works perfectly. But if i first load the "#/"  and then **route**  to "#/chat" my chat is not working.

i am very new to the Signal R so i don't know the issue actually.
here is my code:

**app.js**

```
module.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            controller: "ItemsController",
            templateUrl: "/templates/itemsView.html"
        });


        $routeProvider.when("/item/:id", {
            controller: "SingleItemController",
            templateUrl: "/templates/singleItemView.html"
        });


        $routeProvider.when("/login", {
            controller: "LoginController",
            templateUrl: "/templates/loginView.html"
        });

        $routeProvider.when("/chat", {
            controller: "ChatController",
            templateUrl: "/templates/chatView.html"
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
    });

  $(function () {
       $.connection.hub.logging = true;  //for debugg
       $.connection.hub.start();
  });

   $.connection.hub.error(function (err) {
       console.log('An error occurred: ' + err);
   });

   angular.module('ogateApp').value("chat", $.connection.chat);
```

**ChatHub.cs**

```
  [HubName("chat")]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {   
        public void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.newMessage(message);
        }   

    }
```

**ChatController.js**

```
module.controller("ChatController", function ($scope, chat) {        

    $scope.messages = [];

    $scope.sendMessage = function() {

       chat.server.sendMessage($scope.newMessage);

        $scope.newMessage = "";
    };

    chat.client.newMessage = function (message) {
        $scope.messages.push({ message: message });
        $scope.$apply();
        console.log(message);
    };       

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While debugging i found that the hub was remaining attached to a stale controller that was out of scope.  SignalR was not restarting the hub for the new instance of the controller that was created when you navigated back to our page.

In order to fix this that if you stopped the hub whenever you changed route, then the hub started up again correctly when you navigated back to the initial page.

The following code fixed the issue:

```
app.run([
    '$rootScope', function ($rootScope, security) {

        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, currRoute, prevRoute) {
            $.connection.hub.stop();
        });
}]);
```

For details GO in this [LINK](http://miczdem.wordpress.com/2014/09/04/signalr-with-angular-js-fix-for-signalr-remains-attached-to-a-stale-controller/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have an error in your relative js files path.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Try to use absolute url for testing:

```
<script src="http://localhost:your_port/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Do you have an exception during js debugging ? Can i see your html page (whith js reference)?